# Local connection string of service bus

Tags: servicebus

I have a on-premise service bus installed i want to browse and test in service bus explorer . How can i know the endpoint of my service bus installed locally  and details step by step procedure to test on service bus explorer. Like shared secret key all the attribute values in endpoint

Answer (score 2):

The connection string looks something like this

```
Endpoint=sb://<hostname>/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace;StsEndpoint=https://<hostname>:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace;RuntimePort=5671;ManagementPort=9355;TransportType=Amqp
```

The ports are the default when configuring and should be changed accordingly if required.

One thing to note is that the newer releases of Service Bus Explorer do not support Service Bus for Windows Server (which itself is [out of mainstream support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/collaboration-and-federation-azure-service-bus-messaging-on-premises-futures/)) and you would need to use [v2.1 which last supports it](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer#service-bus-explorer-for-windows-server).

Since there seems to be no releases available, you will have to fetch and run the code directly.

Comment: This would have been my answer.  Yes, you need an OLD(ER) version of SB Explorer to talk to on premise.     My addition, if you did load-balancing of nodes, the connection-string will have all N number of hostname(s) in it, IIRC.  It's been a few years.